# Jquery replacement for .html() function that won't try to rewrite the html on Redactor imperavi - Xss vulnerability

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xss, redactor

This is treated as a XSS vulnerability issue. I'm using the redactor component from [Imperavi](https://imperavi.com/), and it seems like it can't generate the right output value when the Html is not valid.

The problem is when we insert strings like this:

```
<<SCRIPT a=2>qssQ5GkdwWU=7;//<</SCRIPT>
```

The redactor removes the script tags and generates this string. This is expected because of XSS attacks.

```
<qssQ5GkdwWU=7;//<
```

The problem happens then the redactor tries to set the previous value to the redactor element using `html.(html)`. It will think that there is an element and will output this:

```
<qssq5gkdwwu=7;> </qssq5gkdwwu=7;>
```

How can I set the value to the element but preventing this behavior?

Comment: Can you create a snippet to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override JQuery's `htmlPrefilter`function:

```js
htmlPrefilter: function( html ) {
  return html;
},
```

If special character are the issue then try escaping them like this:

```js
// trying to set following string as innerHTML
let c = '<qssQ5GkdwWU=7;//<';

// with default jquery
$('.one').html(c);


// modify filter function, and do your own character escaping 
jQuery.htmlPrefilter = function(html) {
  let clean = html.replace(/[&<"']/g, function(m) {
    switch (m) {
      case '&':
        return '&amp;';
      case '<':
        return '&lt;';
      case '"':
        return '&quot;';
      default:
        return '&#039;';
    }
  });

  return clean;
}

// now try on second div
$('.two').html(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
One:<span class="one"></span><br> 
Two:<span class="two"></span><br>
```

Execute above script preferably before you load Redactor.

---

If you decide to do your own sanitization then you could use [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) or similar library.

```js
let content = 'Malicius content <img src="https://dummyimage.com/30" onload="this.style.border=`2px solid red`;alert(`attacked! :p`);" >';
// default jquery
$('.one').html(content);


// modify filter function, do your own sanitization
jQuery.htmlPrefilter = function(html) {
  html = DOMPurify.sanitize(html);
  console.log('sanitized: ', html)
  return html;
}

// trying on second div
$('.two').html(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dompurify/2.3.4/purify.min.js" integrity="sha512-jGh38w63cHRzfBHtyKgEMMkJswUFXDA3YXrDjaE8ptzxV5DDkLDUDjtGUy5tmDkOXHWsItKfFjocaEtj1WuVnQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

One:<span class="one"></span><br> Two:
<span class="two"></span><br>
```

First image gets red border. And because of the sanitization second doesn't.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Do you think overriding htmlPrefilter() is safe? I mean, it would affect an entire application. Just trying to think if there could be any situation where sanitizing is not ideal.

Comment: You are right. We need to do sanitization only where you take user input or display user input as html. In this case, `<qssQ5GkdwWU=7;//<` only opening angle bracket is the problem. So more correct logic would be, if you don't find corresponding closing bracket then escape the opening bracket.